# group by one column, find max of another and display the remaining columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`. I need to group by column `a`, find max of column `b` but want to display all the columns in `df` as well.

For example -

df:

```py
    a       b       c      d
0   259992  20     55      abc
1   259992  10     12      def
2   1912687 11     11      ghi
```

My code to find max of `b`:

```py
df.groupby('a')['b'].max().reset_index()
```

This gives me a partial result:

```py
    a       b   
0   259992  20 
1   1912687 11
```

What I want to obtain is:

```py
    a       b       c      d
0   259992  20     55      abc
1   1912687 11     11      ghi
```

Any tips on how to do this in the most efficient manner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('a')['b'].idxmax()]
```

---

```
         a   b   c    d
0   259992  20  55  abc
2  1912687  11  11  ghi
```